# How can I make a clickable arc that would fill the arc to the point where the user clicked?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, css

After fiddling around with using polygons and javascript to try to get satisfactory results. It seems I out of options on how to make this.

The situation is this, I got have to .png images whereby one shows the thermostat and the second shows the progress, I project the progress on top of the thermostat and now the idea is that when I click somewhere on the dial, the progress is shown from the left side to the point the user clicked.

[image: Full radial]
[image: Half radial]

I have been looking for libraries or tips to help me achieve what I want but no luck so far so that is why I ask here. Can anyone give me guidance on how the achieve this result? I cannot change the design of the thermostat because that has been agreed on but I can almost any library out there for this.
I'm using a .NET Razer page to make this (HTML, CSS, jQuery)

I tried using polygons to hide the part of the image that should not be visible to the user this did not had the desired effect. I also tried asking ChatGPT to see if it could come with any solution but that also didn't work.

Here is what I tried with polygon using javascript

```
const container = document.querySelector('.thermostat');
const progress = document.querySelector('.thermo-ring');
console.log('JS Loaded')

progress.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    // Get the x coordinate of the click event relative to the progress image
    const x = event.offsetX;

    // Calculate the progress value based on the x coordinate
    const maxValue = progress.offsetWidth;
    let progressValue = x / maxValue;
    progressValue = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, progressValue)); // clamp to [0, 1]

    // Set the clip-path of the progress image to show the progress up to the clicked point
    const polygonPoints = `50% 0, 0 0, 0 100%, ${progressValue * 100}% 100%, ${progressValue * 100}% 50%, 50% 50%`;
    progress.style.clipPath = `polygon(${polygonPoints})`;

    // Show the progress image by setting its opacity to 1
    progress.style.opacity = 1;
});
```

The expected result is that if you click somewhere on the dial, the progress is shown to that point starting from the left side like in the second image.

Comment: Create an SVG as @Lain suggested, because you have to define just one nudge (of the 68) and `<use>` that 68 times, properly rotated into position. Best is an *in-document* SVG for direct access with CSS. Would be beneficial to responsiveness too, as the graphics are being taken care of without you having to worry about anti-aliassing and loading the properly sized image.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I was already talking SVG's into consideration but it seems indeed to be the most logical step forward, time to get to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might not really help you, but I would just draw that dial as svg, since I had control over each separate section and I could add attributes with level/order and status on it.

### Here is a quick sample

```js
const tRects = document.querySelectorAll('rect[data-order]');
tRects.forEach(rect => {
  //rect.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event){
  rect.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event){
    tRects.forEach(rect => {
      if(Number(this.dataset.order) >= Number(rect.dataset.order)){
        rect.classList.add('hover')
      }
      else{
        rect.classList.remove('hover')
      }
    })
  })
})
```

```css
svg{
  background: blue
}

rect.hover{
  fill: red
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <rect x="0" y="0" height="20" width="10" fill = "#000" data-order="1" />
  <rect x="11" y="2" height="20" width="10" fill = "#111" data-order="2" />
  <rect x="22" y="4" height="20" width="10" fill = "#222" data-order="3" />
  <rect x="33" y="6" height="20" width="10" fill = "#333" data-order="4" />
  <rect x="44" y="8" height="20" width="10" fill = "#444" data-order="5" />
  <rect x="55" y="10" height="20" width="10" fill = "#555" data-order="6" />
  <rect x="66" y="12" height="20" width="10" fill = "#666" data-order="7" />
  <rect x="77" y="14" height="20" width="10" fill = "#777" data-order="8" />
  <rect x="88" y="14" height="20" width="10" fill = "#888" data-order="9" />
  <rect x="99" y="12" height="20" width="10" fill = "#999" data-order="10" />
  <rect x="110" y="10" height="20" width="10" fill = "#aaa" data-order="11" />
  <rect x="121" y="8" height="20" width="10" fill = "#bbb" data-order="12" />
  <rect x="132" y="6" height="20" width="10" fill = "#ccc" data-order="13" />
  <rect x="143" y="4" height="20" width="10" fill = "#ddd" data-order="14" />
  <rect x="154" y="2" height="20" width="10" fill = "#eee" data-order="15" />
  <rect x="165" y="0" height="20" width="10" fill = "#fff" data-order="16" />
</svg>
```